# servlet not forwarding session attribute to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, embedded-tomcat-8

Using embedded tomcat, this code works:

**Servlet**:

```
String test = "test";
request.setAttribute("test", test);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

**JSP**:

```
<%= request.getAttribute("test") %>
```

It sets the attribute `test` and then prints it out on the servlet `/example`'s jsp page `example.jsp`.

---

However, if I try to set the attribute within the session then I don't get the same result, instead, I get a `null` when using this:

**Servlet**:

```
String test = "test";
request.getSession().setAttribute("test", test);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

**JSP**:

```
<%= session.getAttribute("test") %>
```

Comment: Is the variable test null by any chance?

Comment: If you put something in the session with `request.getSession().setAttribute` you have to read it from the session, not the request. Try `<%= session.getAttribute("test") %>` (which I think is what @jedison was trying to suggest)

Comment: yep but now you'll see when it works :)

Comment: What about switching from NetBeans IDE to Eclipse and dumping the embedded Tomcat? Switch to the real external Tomcat.

Comment: No, no, it's not that, it's just that I use Eclipse and they have a Tomcat deployment plugin so I don't need embedded Tomcat. It just works.

Comment: Yes, yes, I saw them. But I prefer not to use embedded Tomcat. I'll try it if you really think that is the issue.

Comment: Yes, yes, I'm aware of that. I just prefer the real Tomcat to the embedded Tomcat (as I use Tomcat a lot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the JSP side, you don't need to say `request.getSession()`, just `session.getAttribute();`
And you had a problem in your Main.java when creating the servlet context (a trick of using embedded Tomcat); you were not getting the context created by adding the webapp to tomcat, you had some other context.

```
//          File base = new File("src/main/webapp");
//          context = tomcat.addContext("", base.getAbsolutePath());
//          tomcat.addWebapp(null, "/", base.getAbsolutePath());

        context = tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File("src/main/webapp").getAbsolutePath());
        context.setSessionTimeout(10080);
```

I commented out your code and changed the context handling and now things work. And a new exception to be caught.

```
        } catch (ServletException | InterruptedException | LifecycleException exception) {
```

Comment: That doesn't change way code will work so it will not solve anything. If you want to suggest improvements post them as comments, not as answers.

Comment: Totò posted his answer when I wasn't looking at this question. I can't comment on every non-answer and explain why it is not answer simply because I don't spend my entire day in front of computer reading StarckOverflow. If you feel that this is bad answer you should leave a comment under it just like I did under your answer (which I still believe is more like improvements than solution so should be deleted and posted as comment).

Comment: This works fine in my application, so I see no reason why it will not work for ThreaT. On the JSP side, you do not deal with the request object. You deal with the request on the server side.

Comment: No, this runs on WebSphere for me, but I am sure that it would work on embedded or external Tomcat. Have you done a clean stop and republish? Embedded Tomcat is sometimes capricious about properly deploying and updating.

Comment: Possible, but that would surprise me a lot. I would assume some other issue, maybe missing settings in your web.xml, session timeout set too short, ...

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that later.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to compare the session id in the servlet and the jsp. If they are different maybe check your session and cookie configuration in tomcat