# getSession().getAttribute("....") -> null

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I created a signIn servlet:

```
@WebServlet(
    name = "SignInServlet",
    description = "check email & pass",
    urlPatterns = {"/authorization_signin"}
    )
public class SignInServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {

public SignInServlet(){
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    UserDataSet user = new UserDataSet();
    SignInModel modelSignIn = new SignInModel();


    user.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
    user.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));

    user = modelSignIn.doSignIn(user);

    if (request.getSession().getAttribute("loggedUser") == null) {
        if (user != null) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("loggedUser", user);             request.getRequestDispatcher("authorization.jsp").forward(request, response);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Email or password is incorrect");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }
    }

}

@Override
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
}
}
```

When user is signed in, servlet redirects him to "authorization.jsp"

```
<body>
<%

if (request.getSession().getAttribute("loggedUser") != null){
    UserDataSet user = (UserDataSet) request.getSession().getAttribute("loggedUser");

    System.out.println("In author :" + request.getSession().getAttribute("loggedUser"));
%>
<h1> Hello <%= user.getFirstName() %> <%= user.getLastName() %>!</h1>
<h2>AUTORIZED!</h2>
 <a href="/authorization_logout">Log Out</a>
 <%
 }
else {
%>
 <h1>GO HOME</h1>
 <%
}
 %>
 </body>
```

Then browser shows this page and data for signed in user

If write into URL "localhost:8080" and go to "index.jsp", then
 again on "authorization.jsp"

Filter check session:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "LoginFilter")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {
public void destroy() {
}



public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

    System.out.println("Enter filter");

    System.out.println("Filter session: " + httpRequest.getSession(false).getAttribute("loggedUser"));



    UserDataSet user = (UserDataSet) httpRequest.getSession(false).getAttribute("loggedUser");

    if (user != null) {
        System.out.println("CHAIN");
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    } else {
        httpResponse.sendRedirect("/");
        System.out.println("Not signin");
    }
}

public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {

}

}
```

And `getSession().getAttribute("loggedUser")` returns  `null`
Why?

Next text:
If I signed in and servlet open "authorization.jsp", then try to go throw URL on any *.jsp where session will be checked and the result will be `null`

What's wrong?

Comment: which file return null?

Comment: @atiqkhaled filter, and *.jsp where session checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend had help me found answer for this question in some answers on `stackoverflow`

> If you put something in the session with request.getSession().setAttribute you have to read it from the session, not the request. Try <%= session.getAttribute("test") %>

[Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23167654/servlet-not-forwarding-session-attribute-to-jsp)

Comment: Yes,in jsp page you have to call like this.

Comment: This solved my problem. It's strange because in one case using request it worked but using session work in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
  <%=  request.getParameter("loggedUser") %>
```

For some reason I saw [1] in java logs when I used  request.getSession().getAttribute("loggedUser") , I also observed in the same code that request.getParameter works, at least when values are passed by query strings and the "unchecked or unsafe operations" disappears from the log .
So seems to me that can be a solution for this question.

[1]

```
_index__jsp.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25982613)